# I need to create a speedTest view. How can I add a gradient color using tubeSpeedometer

Tags: java, android

> **I am trying to create a speedtest using TubeSpeedometer class. But I cannot change the color using gradient since there is no method for adding a drawable.The view that I have created works fine if I assign a hex code but when I am trying to create a gradient so that I am have 3 colors.It does not work**

**Currently showing like This:**

[image: current speedtest view]

**I need the view to be like below :**
[image: tubespeedometer]

**TubeSpeedometer view**

> build.gradle

```
  .........................................................................
     // dependencies
     implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.50"
     implementation 'com.github.anastr:speedviewlib:1.5.0'
   .........................................................................
```

> XML

```
         <com.github.anastr.speedviewlib.TubeSpeedometer
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:id="@+id/tubeSpeedometer"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                    android:visibility="visible"
                                    app:sv_indicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                                    app:sv_indicatorLightColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                                    app:sv_maxSpeed="100"
                                    app:sv_tickPadding="50dp"
                                    app:sv_tickRotation="false"
                                    app:sv_speedTextColor="@android:color/transparent"
                                    app:sv_speedometerBackColor="@color/speed_gradient"
                                    app:sv_textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                                    app:sv_unit="Mbps"
                                    app:sv_unitTextColor="@android:color/transparent"
                                    app:sv_withTremble="true" />
      
 .......................................................................................                      
                    **Gradient xml** 
        
                     <pre>Gradient file for color</pre>
    


                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <gradient xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:startColor="#5253D0"
                android:endColor="#60D1FA"
                android:angle="145"
                android:startX="30"
                android:endX="70"
                android:startY="30"
                android:endY="70"
                android:type="linear"/>
```

---

> Java

```
   **SpeedTest Activity**
```

> ```
> Adding section and now I am trying to create a new gradient color that can look like ookla speedtest
> ```

```
                List<Section> sections = new ArrayList<>();
                sections.add(new Section(.25f, Color.rgb(0,119,200)));
                
                ((TubeSpeedometer) findViewById(R.id.tubeSpeedometer)).makeSections(1);
                
                // ((TubeSpeedometer) findViewById(R.id.tubeSpeedometer)).clearSections();
                ((TubeSpeedometer) findViewById(R.id.tubeSpeedometer)).addSections(sections);
                   
  ((TubeSpeedometer)findViewById(R.id.tubeSpeedometer)).setSpeedometerBackColor(R.color.speed_gradient);
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You can add 3 color gradients with `android:centerColor` attribute in your speed_gradient.xml.

```
<gradient xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:startColor="#5253D0"
                android:centerColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:endColor="#60D1FA"
                android:angle="145"
                android:startX="30"
                android:endX="70"
                android:startY="30"
                android:endY="70"
                android:type="linear"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mythos, the  problem I have is that when I setSpeedometer ,((TubeSpeedometer)findViewById(R.id.tubeSpeedometer)).setSpeedometerBackColor(R.color.speed_gradient)  , it does not change the color using gradient that I have created.

Comment: @Deza This will answer your question: https://github.com/anastr/SpeedView/issues/86

Comment: If you have any library-specific queries, you should use that github issues page to raise new issues. I'm afraid Stackoverflow won't be of much help.